# How to everlap two background images

Tags: html, css, svg, background, background-image

```css
section.contact {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

section.contact {
  background-image: url('https://svgshare.com/i/XxP.svg'), url('https://svgshare.com/i/Xwg.svg');
  background-position: bottom, top right;
  background-position-y: bottom, 20px;
  background-size: 100%, 40%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<section class="contact">
</section>
```

I have two background images, and I want the second one to overlap the first one, like this:

[image]

but instead some kind of transparency is applied, ending up like this:

[image]

This is the css code:

```css
section.contact {
      background-image: url('/assets/contact/contact-bg.svg'), url('/assets/contact/contact-img.svg');
      background-position: bottom, top right;
      background-size: 100%, 40% ;
    }
```

I want the contact-img.svg image to overlap the contact-bg.svg image.

The contact-img.svg file starts like this:

```xml
<svg width="233" height="158" viewBox="0 0 233 158" fill="none" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule=[...]
```

I tried adding a `fill-opacity="1"` like this:

```xml
<svg width="233" height="158" viewBox="0 0 233 158" fill="none" fill-opacity="1"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd"
[...]
```

But it didn't work

Comment: Can you provide whole snippet with this?

Comment: sure, I just added a snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing order of urls and other properties should do the trick.

Every next value in `background-image` is placed below previous in z axis and the first image has an opacity that is why i looked like it is blended with one another.

```css
section.contact {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

section.contact {
  background-image: url(https://svgshare.com/i/Xwg.svg), url(https://svgshare.com/i/XxP.svg);
  background-position: top right, bottom;
  background-position-y: 20px, bottom;
  background-size: 40%, 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<section class="contact">
</section>
```

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot, couldn't find anywhere the exaplanation you mentioned. BTW, I don't know why you were downvoted...

Comment: I couldn't find this explanation either and it was my guess that happened to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a container, put them inside it, give it a value of position: relative. Make the two images position: absolute, then you will be able to freely do anything with them in terms of overlaping.

Answer (score 0):

**I think this should solve your problem. Let me know if there is any issue with this.Make sure to use your images for the code**

```
 .under {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 z-index: -1;
 }

 .over {
 position: absolute;
 left: 40px;
 top: 10px;
 z-index: -1;
 }
 
 <img src="https://tafttest.com/184x46.png" width="184" height="46" class="under" />
 <img src="https://tafttest.com/100x84.png" width="100" height="84" class="over" />
```